# Fetch File content issue

Tags: iphone, ios

In My app I am trying to fetch content of file which extension is .txt and file is with in the app. I am trying below

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Last"
                                         ofType:@"txt"];

content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                       error:NULL];

lines = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"Content Length: %i", [lines count]);
NSLog(@"%@ %@",content,path);
```

but content and path print `null`. any body know whats wrong with it?

Thanks.

Comment: Check Last.txt is included in your project !! ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that Last.txt is not in the project, to verify in the Project Navigator click on your project (top level item), go to Build Phases, and check that the file is in "Copy Bundle Resources"